# How to make some Django settings accessible by staff?

Tags: python, django, settings

In Django, settings are stored in a file, settings.py. This file is part of the code, and goes into the repository. It is only the developers who deal with this file. The admin deals with the models, the data in the database. This is the data that the non-development staff edits, and the site visitors see rendered in templates.

The thing is, our site, and many others, have lots of settings options that should be edited by non-developer staff. We're talking about stand-alone site-wide constants that really have no place in the database. Putting them in the database will result in numerous pointless queries. Caching could alleviate that, but that seems unnecessarily complex to handle what can be done with a single line in the settings.py file.

I did notice [this dbsettings app](http://code.google.com/p/django-values/), but it is old and unmaintained. I also noticed that the django e-commerce app, Satchmo, includes a use-case specific fork of this dbsettings app. We could build something similar into our site, an app that stores some settings as key/value pairs in a single database table, but it just really seems like the wrong approach. Why put something in the DB that doesn't belong there just to make it more easily editable by non-developers?

We have a list of site-wide settings on our Django site that we want to be editable by non-developer administrators. What is the best way of going about this?

Comment: +1 because knowing this could make it easier to manage Django projects in VCS. Developers have to be careful not to commit local changes to settings.py otherwise.

Comment: caching will alleviate this (when local settings are put into the database) to only one query per instance of django process.

Comment: to restart the server in order to reload settings you can just call "touch site.wsgi" file, e.g. with a cron job, but this will work only if your wsgi process runs in daemon mode

Comment: It might help to give some examples of the type of administrator settings you are talking about. `settings.py` is for deployment-time configuration so there is obviously an impedance mismatch with what you're trying to do at run-time. Completely dismissing a database-driven solution seems like a premature optimization to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like [dbsettings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dbsettings) (as you mentioned) seems like the way to go. From the [reasons for existence](https://github.com/zlorf/django-dbsettings#storing-settings-in-the-database) for that project:

> Not all settings belong in
>   `settings.py`, as it has some
>   particular limitations:
>
> - Settings are project-wide. This not only requires apps to clutter up
>       `settings.py`, but also increases the chances of naming
>     conflicts.
> - Settings are constant throughout an instance of Django. They cannot be
>       changed without restarting the application.
> - Settings require a programmer in order to be changed. This is true even
>       if the setting has no functional impact on anything else.

If dbsettings doesn't work for you, then implement your own, or fork it. It doesn't seem like it'd be too arduous.

Answer (score 6):

I'm actually a big fan of dbsettings, <strike>and keep meaning to publish my fork that patches it to work with Django 1.1 (not actually a big change)</strike>. Looks like someone has [updated it already](http://github.com/sciyoshi/django-dbsettings).

However, you're probably right that this is overkill for what you need. One thing I've done before is to add a line to the end of settings.py that imports and parses a YAML file. YAML is a simple markup language, which at its most basic is just `KEY: VALUE` ...

```
CONSTANT1: MyValue
CONSTANT2: Anothervalue
```

If you put this somewhere editors can access it, then at the end of settings.py you just do:

```
import yaml
try:
    globals().update(yaml.load(open('/path/to/my/yaml/file.yml')))
except:
    pass
```

You'll need the [Python YAML](http://pyyaml.org/) library to parse the YML file.

The downside to this approach is that you'll need to restart Apache to get it to pick up the changes.

**Edited to add** It wouldn't be particularly difficult to build a front end which could edit this file, and provide a button which runs a script to restart Apache.

Comment: This solution doesn't work because only tech people can edit files on the server and/or restart the apache.

Comment: It wouldn't be particularly difficult to build a front end which could edit this file, and provide a button which runs a script to restart Apache.

Comment: @Daniel - though at that point you're getting into the same kind of work-level that dbsettings requires.

Answer (score 1):

If you must avoid server restarts then a logical place for the settings is the database as Dominic and Daniel said, but you'll need to invalidate cached settings object every time it is updated.

Looks like it's possible to re-set values in the cache with Django's [low level cache API](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api). All you want should be achievable with these calls:

```
 cache.set('settings', local_settings)
 cache.add('settings', local_settings)
 local_settings = cache.get('settings')
 cache.delete('settings')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about putting a sitesettings.py (or whatever) somewhere that your admins can access, then in settings.py do

```
from sitesettings import *
```

That seems good and simple, but I may have misunderstood or oversimplified your problem :)

Comment: This solution also doesn't work because only tech people can edit files on the server and/or restart the apache.

Answer (score 0):

models.py

```
class Setting(models.Model):
    """Global settings for app"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

admin.py

```
from YOUR_APP.models import Setting
class SettingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'name',
        'value',
    )
admin.site.register(Setting, SettingAdmin)
```

extras.py

```
@register.filter
def get_setting(name):
    setting = Setting.objects.get(name=name)
    return setting.value
```

template.html

```
{% if 'setting_name'|get_setting == 'true' %}
    Display your Feature
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Django Packages has a [page](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/live-setting/) that lists packages that provide such functionality - most query the database and then use caching to minimize hits on the DB.

I found [Django Dynamic Preferences](https://github.com/agateblue/django-dynamic-preferences) to be of particular interest due to the fine-grained control it gives you over the configuration.